# How can shift some portion of a table to another page?

Tags: tables

I have table code of `latex` like following code. This table exceeds one page but it doesn't appear another page. How can I shift some portion of table to another page. ? Please need help..

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=0cm,right=0cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Review .}
\author{Rezwan}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
% \vtop{\hbox{\strut }\hbox{\strut }\hbox{\strut }}
% \vtop{\hbox{\strut }\hbox{\strut }}
\end{abstract}

\section{Summary of Spectra-based Bio-marker Measurement Proposals}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Summary of Spectra-based Bio-marker Measurement Proposals}
\label{tab:spectra_summary}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{| l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l |}
\hline
\textbf{Ref} & \textbf{Purpose} & \textbf{Spectrometer} & \textbf{Range($nm$)}& \textbf{Used($nm$)}& \textbf{Sample}&\textbf{Algo.}& \textbf{Acc.}\\ \hline
%===ROW======================================== Glucose 1
\cite{li2017reagent}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&BA FT-IR&2500-11764.71&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 8673.03,}\hbox{\strut 9033.42,}\hbox{\strut 9267.84,}\hbox{\strut 9661.84}}&WBS&PLS&$R^2$=0.947\\\hline
%===ROW======================================== 2
\cite{kasahara2018noninvasive}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&BT-27,BV-70& 8333.33-10204.08&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 9090.91,}\hbox{\strut 9345.79,}\hbox{\strut 9523.81}}&WBS&MLR&CC=0.36\\\hline
%===ROW======================================== 3
\cite{yu2014vitro}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&GXI FT-IR&19191.18-9765.62&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 9259.26,}\hbox{\strut 9661.84}} &Body&PLS&-\\\hline
%===ROW========================================4
\cite{burmeister1999evaluation}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&Nicolet 740 FT-IR&1515.15-1851.85&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 1612.90,}\hbox{\strut 1689.19,}\hbox{\strut 1731.60}}&Forefinger&PLS&-\\\hline
%===ROW========================================5
\cite{shih2015noninvasive}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&Raman spectra&5871.99-33670.03&-&Dog's Ear&PLS&$R^{2}$=0.92\\\hline
%===ROW========================================6
\cite{vranvcic2011continuous}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&FT-IR&9389.67-9900.99&9689.92 &Finger&\color{red}QCLS&$R^{2}$=0.9991\\\hline
%===ROW========================================7
\cite{bauer2018ir}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&Photothermal&8032.13-9852.22&8928.57&Hand&PLS&-\\\hline
%===ROW========================================8
\cite{jintao2017noninvasive}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&BM-F FT-NIR&833.33-2500&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 1332.98-}\hbox{\strut 2354.77}}&Rat's Leg&\vtop{\hbox{\strut PLS}\hbox{\strut ANN}}&\vtop{\hbox{\strut $R^{2}$=0.9622}\hbox{\strut $R^{2}$=0.9279}}\\\hline
%===ROW========================================9
\cite{li2010nonlinear}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&NIR Quest 256-2.5&900-2500&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 1450,}\hbox{\strut 1900}}&Body&mUVE-KPLS&\vtop{\hbox{\strut RMSEP=58.1,}\hbox{\strut 9.4 mg$dL^{-1}$}}\\\hline
%===ROW========================================10
\cite{scholtes2014raman}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&Raman&5500.55-18484.29&-&Forearm&PLS&$R^{2}$=0.83\\\hline
%===ROW========================================11
\cite{goodarzi2016selection}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&Bruker MPA FT-NIR&800-2500&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 2100-}\hbox{\strut 2300}}&Serum&Forward iPLS &RMSEP=1.57 mM\\\hline
%===ROW======================================== Cancer 12
\cite{xiao2016non}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{cancer.png}&BWS456-785&5714.29-16666.67&9970.09&Serum&OPLS-DA&ROC=0.991\\\hline
%===ROW========================================13
\cite{feng2017noninvasive}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{cancer.png}&confocal Raman&5882.35-16666.67&-&Urine&PLS-DA&\vtop{\hbox{\strut $a^{nas}$=96.4\%,}\hbox{\strut $a^{eso}$=95.8\%}}\\\hline
%===ROW========================================14
\cite{feng2016biophysical}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{cancer.png}&confocal micro-Raman&-&830&Skin&OLS&-\\\hline
%===ROW========================================15
\cite{shao2017evaluation}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{cancer.png}&RRm&5555.56-25000&6313.13&EPS,Serum&PCA,LDA&\vtop{\hbox{\strut $a^{EPS}$=75\%,}\hbox{\strut $a^{Serum}$=68\%}}\\\hline
%===ROW========================================16
\cite{masilamani2012fluorescence}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{cancer.png}&Elico LS 70&200-800&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 390,}\hbox{\strut 450}}&Blood,Urine&-&\vtop{\hbox{\strut Sen=80\%,}\hbox{\strut $Spec=78\%$}}\\\hline
%===ROW========================================17
\cite{kutsanedzie2018near}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{Volatile_Organic.png}&Portable NIRS&800-2500&1800&Fingerprints&PLS&-\\\hline
%===ROW========================================18
\cite{reber2018non}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{hemoglobin.jpg}&MSOT&700-970&800&Mice,Humans&\vtop{\hbox{\strut Custom-built}\hbox{\strut MATLAB algo}}&p-value<0.05\\\hline
%===ROW========================================19
\cite{wang2017hemaapp}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{hemoglobin.jpg}&Smartphone&600-1300&940&Fingertip&SVM&Pc=0.62\\\hline
%===ROW========================================20
\cite{gurm2017multi}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{tissue.png}&MSI datasets&-&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 740,}\hbox{\strut 780,}\hbox{\strut 850,}\hbox{\strut 945}}&Hand&MLP&$91.3\%$\\\hline
%===ROW========================================21 Glucose 
\cite{yadav2014near}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&NIR LED&750-2500&940&Forearm&\vtop{\hbox{\strut Signal}\hbox{\strut Processing}}&-\\\hline

%===ROW========================================22
\cite{song2015impedance}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}&&&\vtop{\hbox{\strut 850,}\hbox{\strut 950}\hbox{\strut 1300}}&&ANN&\\\hline

%===ROW========================================
\cite{}&\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{tissue.png}&&&&&&\\\hline

\pagebreak

\multicolumn{8}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{glucose.png}=Glucose}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{BA=Bruker Alpha,WBS=whole blood samples}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{BT=Bruker Tensor,BV=Bruker Vertex,MLR=Multiple Linear Regression, CC= Correlation Coefficient}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{BM-F=Bruker Matrix-F,FT-IR=Fourier Transform Infrared}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\color{red}QCLS=Quantum Cascade Laser Signal}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{mUVE-KPLS=modified Uninformative Variable Elimination-Kernel Partial Least Squares}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Md3RNN=Multi-division deep dynamic Recurrent Neural Network)}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{cancer.png}=Cancer}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{OPLS-DA=Orthogonal Partial Least Squares Discriminant Analysis}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{PLS-DA= Partial Least Squares Discriminant Analysis,RRm=Renishaw Raman microscope}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{$a^{nas}$=Accuracy of nasopharyngeal cancer cancer, $a^{eso}$=Accuracy of esophageal cancer}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{OLS=Ordinary least-squares}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{EPS=Expressed Prostatic Secretion}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{Volatile_Organic.png}=Volatile Organic Compounds}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.03\textwidth]{hemoglobin.jpg}=Hemoglobin}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{MSOT=Multi-Spectral Optoacoustic Tomography,Pc=Pearson correlation}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{tissue.png=Tissue}\\
\multicolumn{8}{c}{MLP=Multi-Layer Perceptron}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add a full, compilable code, a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: A `tabular` cannot be split over pages. Have a look at `longtable`.

Comment: @Johannes_B , I got error for using `longtable`

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque We need to your help to help you. Unless you tell us what is your complete code, what kind of errors you are getting, it will be impossible for us to contribute. 
Just as a guess, I can tell that `longtable`s *can not* be floated. You may want to take a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215443/14103).

Comment: @Masroor, Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove environment `table` around `longtable` and move the `\caption` inside the latter. Then `longtable` can span several pages, float objects like `table` cannot.