# Create table question

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I would like to create a table like the one I show in the image but I'm a bit lost.

[image]

Let's see if someone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! for start see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. also look for answers on question tagged as `tables`. here on site are tons of similar question.

Comment: For 'number of operations'  take a look ath the `\multicolumn` command and for 'Database'  you might want to have a look at the `\multirow` command.

Comment: The answers to [Using multicolumn in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131867/134144) and [How to use \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73283/134144) might give you an idea on how to use the above mentioned commands. Apart from that, please show what you tried so far by including a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Comment: Are you mainly interested in reproducing the boring table shown in the screenshot exactly as is, or might you be interested in learning how to show the tabular information in a more appealing and inviting way?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution which uses the `l` column type for the first column and the `r` column type for the six data columns. To give the table material a more open "look", no vertical lines are drawn, and the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package are used in place of `\hline` and `\cline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{r} @{}} % "@{}" eliminates horizontal whitespace padding.
\toprule
Database & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Number of operations} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
        &  10 &  50 &  100 & 1000 & 10000 & 100000 \\
\midrule
MongoDB &  61 &  75 &   84 &  387 &  2693 &  23354 \\ 
RavenDB & 570 & 898 & 1213 & 6939 & 71343 & 740450 \\ 
\ldots\\
MS Sql Express & 30 & 94 & 129 & 1790 & 15588 & 216479 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [novski's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469829/134144), here is a variant using rules from `booktabs` for a more open appearance and `siunitx` for better alignment of number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[group-minimum-digits=4]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l
                 S[table-format=3]
                 S[table-format=3]
                 S[table-format=4]
                 S[table-format=4]
                 S[table-format=5]
                 S[table-format=6]}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2.5}{*}{Database} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Number of operations} \\
  \cmidrule{2-7}
                    & 10 & 50 & 100 & 1000 & 10000 & 100000\\
  \midrule
  MongoDB           & 61 & 75 & 84 & 387 & 2693 & 23354 \\ 
  RavenDB           & 570 & 898 & 1213 & 6939 & 71343 & 740450 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is the variant without the `\multirow`:

```
 \toprule
 Database & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Number of operations} \\
 \cmidrule{2-7}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to add the `siunitx` option `group-minimum-digits=4` to avoid some unevenness across rows.

Comment: In addition to `group-minimum-digits=4`, the last column should have `S[table-format=7]`. I'd not use `\multirow`, as the upper left cell has no reason for being lowered, being a first level header.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your suggestion. I have implemented into the answer.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your correction and suggestion as well. I have implemened both in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i use this dependencies:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

~

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Database} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Number of operations} \\\cline{2-7}
                    & 10 & 50 & 100 & 1000 & 10000 & 1000000\\\hline\endhead
  MongoDB           & 61 & 75 & 84 & 387 & 2693 & 23354 \\ 
  RavenDB           & 570 & 898 & 1213 & 6939 & 71343 & 740450 \\ \hline
\caption{Database evaluation}
\label{tab:databaseeval}
\end{longtable}
```

[image: picturewithcaption]

Comment: Why do you usa a `longtable`?  The table in the question seems to be short enought to fit onto a single page.

Comment: i use longtable for everything because it wraps the environement 'table' and lets you directly write the caption and label in to the begin without doubling the env. like table-tabular. i will add that to the sample.

Comment: "`longtable` is not a floating environment."  (See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215443/134144)  You might want to keep that in mind when using `longtable`.

Comment: In the OP's screenshot, the numbers in the six data columns are **r**ight-aligned, not **c**entered. You may want to mention how the OP could get right-aligned numbers.

Comment: You wrote "i use longtable for everything because it wraps the environement 'table' ."  What if the table is fairly short (as is the case here) and should *not*, under any circumstance, be broken across pages?

Comment: I then use \newpage in the last styling pf my document